# How can I build the setup.exe file in visual studio?

Tags: c++, installation, exe

I have a C++ game that I have made with Visual Studio 2022. I have built the setup.exe and setup.msi. But my friends are not able to run that game after installing it. On the other hand the setup files works perfectly on my computer.
But they get this error message:

> The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b) Click here
> to close the application

[image: The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b) Click here to close the application]

Comment: Did you include the appropriate runtime distributions?

Comment: 0x76  ( in decimal 123) is usually a file not found error. Do you have a hard-coded file path or directory name that perhaps does not exist on your friend's machine?